# jpackage creates damaged .app file when used on a functioning .jar file

Tags: java, macos, jar, dmg, jpackage

I have a functioning .jar file called Alphabet.jar. I take the correctly functioning .jar file, and place it in an empty directory, called test/. After running jpackage, I successfully get an Mac app. On running the app by double-clicking, I get the following message:

“GravitySim” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

The .jar file runs successfully alone, on use of:

```
... $ java -jar Alphabet.jar
Warning: the fonts "Times" and "Times" are not available for the Java logical font "Serif", which may have unexpected appearance or behavior. Re-enable the "Times" font to remove this warning.
```

A window/gui is then opened and the program runs within it. Great. I then cd into the parent directory of the test/ directory, and run jpackage:

```
... test/ $ jpackage \                
  --name GravitySim \
  --input test/ \
  --main-jar Alphabet.jar \
  --main-class Alphabet \
  --type dmg
```

This creates a .dmg, I open it, move the .app into applications, and I run it. The "GravitySim is damaged..." error appears. If I use --type app-image instead, the same issue occurs. What could be causing this issue?

I am using:
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-25298 (build 16.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25298 (build 16.0.2+7, mixed mode)

And am on M1 Macbook Air with macOS Sonoma 14.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I perceived the same problem and concluded it is related to MacOS security settings and the fact my application was unsigned (according to Apple).

My solution was to drop .dmg and distribute as .pkg. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76633886/4222206

In practice I used commands to prepare the appimage and finish the pkg. Users have confirmed the pkg install works - I cannot test myself.

```
    jpackage \
      --type app-image \
      --app-version "1.0.0" \
      --copyright Copyright \
      --description "Product 1.0.0" \
      --name "Product" --dest target/appimage \
      --temp target/product-tmp --vendor "queeg" --verbose \
      --icon product/src/main/resources/product_logo.png \
      --input Product-1.0.0/dist \
      --main-jar Product-1.0.0.jar \
      --main-class product.Main --mac-package-name "Product" \
      --resource-dir product/src/jpackage/resources-mac \


    jpackage \
      --type pkg \
      --verbose \
      --app-version "1.0.0" \
      --app-image target/appimage/Product.app \
      --name "Product" \
      --icon product/src/main/resources/product_logo.png \
      --dest target \
      --resource-dir product/src/jpackage/resources-mac \
      --vendor queeg
```

And just to be precise, I used this Java distribution:

```
https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.9%2B9/OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_17.0.9_9.tar.gz
```

Comment: Using --type pkg and the installer still produce a damaged application for me. I don't even intend to distribute this yet, simply to run it as an app. Could you provide more information on how you used .pkg?

Comment: I added some information.